# Under what circumstances does dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^ ... do nothing

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, objective-c-blocks

In the completion routine for

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                   queue:queue
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
```

I am calling

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
{
  NSLog(@"CALLING SUCCESS");
});
```

I have two test applications, in one this works correctly, and the other it does not. What happens is the the log statement does not execute. The queue was created with

```
queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
```

Driving me nuts, it simply refuses to execute at all. I called this during the application launch in both cases. I tried delaying the call for 5 seconds. No matter what I do it will not execute the block in one app but does in the other. If I had some clue on under what circumstances dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()... could fail I might be able to discern the difference.

Note that in the actual code I am calling a block which I want to execute on the main thread. I reduced the test case to just calling NSLog.

UPDATE: The difference is that this code doesn't work on the iOS 5.1 simulator, but does work on 6.0 or 6.1. Why?

UPDATE 2: OK, if I use a default NSURLConnection it does work, but if I use

```
self.connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:NO];
[self.connection setDelegateQueue:queue];
[self.connection start];
```

It doesn't work in iOS 5.1. Beginning to think this might be a bug in 5.1 with setDelegateQueue.

Comment: Try putting a log statement before `dispatch_async` to make sure `completionHandler` is even being run.  There's probably another problem going on.

Comment: It is, I verified that much. sendAsynchronousRequest is being initialed from the main thread so there is run loop support for the completionHandler.

Answer (score 0):

OK, the real problem is this. If you use NSURLConnection's class method

```
+ (void)sendAsynchronousRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
                      queue:(NSOperationQueue *)queue
          completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLResponse *, NSData *, NSError *))handler
```

under iOS 5 or 6 it everything works fine.

If instead (like I did) you implement your own connection handler, i.e. roll your own equivalent to the class method (in my case to avoid caching) by implementing NSURLConnectionDelegate and NSURLConnectionDataDelegate, and calling

```
self.connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:NO];
[self.connection setDelegateQueue:queue];
[self.connection start];
```

then the dispatch_async won't work under iOS 5.X but will work under iOS 6.X. I think Apple fixed a bug.